# compare two apk files to identify repackaged code

Tags: android, reverse

I want to compare two apk files, specifically, repackaged application with the original one and find the difference in the source code to identify the changes. 
At the moment we have to unzip and compare individual files manually to find the code difference. 
Is there a tool or library to do this quickly ? 
There are solutions to find similarity but i want to find the individual class file where the code has been modified. Please advice if you know of any solution.

I don't want to unzip , i am looking something similar to github.com/zyrikby/FSquaDRA but gives actual class/smail files to find changes in code

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using WinMerge.  After unzipping the archives you can use WinMerge to compare the folders and contents and quickly view the differences.

Comment: I don't want to unzip , i am looking something similar to https://github.com/zyrikby/FSquaDRA but gives actual class/smail files to find changes in code